# java.lang.illegalStateException: Butterknife

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, butterknife

I am using butterknife to bind my views so when the activity start, the following exception is thrown

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..package name...}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'l' with ID 2131558524 for field 'tabItem' and method 'check' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.

**Note: I have called Butterknife.bind(this) after setContentView(view) and this view is not optional**

My Code

```
public class HandlingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.container_view)FrameLayout container;
@BindView(R.id.l)TabItem tabItem;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_handling);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.l)void check(){
    StoriesFragment storiesFragment = new StoriesFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_view,storiesFragment).commit();
     }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your id's are declared?

Comment: @ste9206 yes, I have invalidated the cache and restarted the android studio.

Comment: where is your TabItem? is it in the root? it seems not correct to use nullable or optional in a view, you could get NullPointerException

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible if your TabItem is not ready, so try to use this while declaring variable and its respective onclick.

Taken reference from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/343)

```
 @Nullable
 @BindView(R.id.l)TabItem tabItem;

 @Optional
 @OnClick(R.id.l)
  void check(){
     //method logic...
  }
```

Comment: It works!!, Why do we need to add this since the items can't be Nullable or Optional?

Comment: Glad to help, if this solves the problem please accept it as answer, and regarding your question please look at [this](http://craftedcourses.io/all-about-butter-knife-part-1/) to understand `@Nullable` and `@Optional` use case..

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error was because I was using two layouts for different versions:

- activity_login.xml
- activity_login.xml (v21)

I added a **progressBar** in **activity_login.xml** but...

> I forgot to added to **activity_login.xml (v21)**.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error, it was due to wrong layout file was being inflated on the view which didnt have the field in question that was being reported in error.

Comment: Had the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if you have put in `build.gradle` (module:app)

   ```
   dependencies {
   annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
   provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'

   }
   ```
2. check if your id's exists
3. try to add `@OnClick(R.id.l)void check(View v){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me after add the annotation @Optional to @Onclick in my Activity class:

```
@Optional
@OnClick({R.id.your_id_1, R.id.your_id_2})
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.your_id_1:
            break;
        case R.id.your_id_2:
            break;
    }
}
```

Import the dependencies and bind your Activity:

```
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.Optional;

public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

The [Butter Knife GitHub README](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/dc3de280ec8519be764e2e0b616a1e12708b7905/README.md#library-projects) provides instructions:

> To use Butter Knife in a library, add the plugin to your `buildscript`:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>   repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>    }
>   dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
>   }
> }
> ```

and to your app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'your_app_id'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
}

dependencies {
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```